# Tomcat could not find servlet status 404

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I started learning jsp and did some simple web application examples.
I am coding a simple shop and dynamic web-app name is Book0. The index.html redirects

```
response.sendRedirect("/Book0/eshop");
```

while the item list is null (initial access).

Now I deployed the application on tomcat via .war export on eclipse.
I had the servlet coded on servlet.Servlet0;

the web.xml for the app, I added on top welcome file list on generic eclipse web.xml:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>EshopServlet0</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlet.Servlet0</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>EshopServlet0</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/eshop</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My other application has been working so far. But this one hits 404 when redirects to the servlet..
Any ideas what has gone wrong.
Thx

Comment: Have you done some research about 404 status? Could you provide more code to replicate the issue?

Comment: what code do you need? I can just post on pastebin or sumwhere? thx

Comment: Can you browse directly to eshop?

Comment: No. I can't. It's gonna be apache 404..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Bm71VRUp -index.jsp sorry bout syntax.. no jsp... http://pastebin.com/tdcLd5Mh -Servlet0.java it's bit partial unfinished.. just bit

Comment: In Servlet0, you have @WebServlet("Servlet0")   but you also have in your web.xml  <url-pattern>/eshop</url-pattern>.  You only need one and they should agree with each other.  You could remove annotation  or change to @WebServlet("eshop")

Comment: Ohh yess thx.. @rickz That's what the eclipse auto annotations. Thx for pointing that out.

Comment: But now.. Firefox is telling me: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies. I tried on regular (non-private browser), still the same. I also use ABlockEdge and Noscript, but i dont think that causes it..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/919RmJ6b - here the bean and all the code.. if anyone would like to try on eclipse dynamic web app.

Comment: What url is Firefox trying to redirect to?

Comment: http://localhost:8282/Book0/ then http://localhost:8282/Book0/eshop.. all of it does not work, redirect problem. I am not sure and guessing perhaps it was the code.. becoz I did modified some of it from the book that i was reading.. Prolly i am gonna try again tomorrow.. becoz it's late.. if you want to answer. I will be able to mark it correct to be fair. Coz this is actually another issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Servlet0, you have @WebServlet("Servlet0") but you also have in your web.xml /eshop. You only need one and they should agree with each other. You could remove annotation or change to @WebServlet("eshop") or @WebServlet("/eshop")

Comment: Thanks. And I finally solved the probs. The servlet:54 should be setAttribute("eshop.items") not eshop.list. And index.jsp line 14 and 24 should String types. That solves em. Thx